# Filtering selected JSon fields in the DB side

Tags: c#, json, linq

This is my DAL method:

```
public List<Schedule> GetSchedulesWithProfiles(int displayStart, int displayLength, out int allDataCount, out int filteredDatacount, string searchParam = "", string searchDir = "")
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var schedules = context.Schedules.Include(x => x.Profile).Include(x => x.VacationType);
                allDataCount = schedules.Count();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParam))
                {
                    schedules = schedules.Where(c => c.Data.Contains(searchParam));     
                }
                filteredDatacount = schedules.Count();
                if (searchDir == "asc" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDir))
                    schedules = schedules.OrderBy(x => x.Data).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLength);
                else
                    schedules = schedules.OrderByDescending(x => x.Data).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLength);
                return schedules.ToList();
              }
        }
```

As you can see, I do filtering by `Data` fieled in my Db. But in the DB I have `Data` in this format:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Alex",
  "LastName": "Alex",
  "Position": "dev"
}
```

This is just `nvarchar` in the DB. I need to do filtering by `FirstName` and/or `LastName`. How I can implement it? Is exist any way to Deserialize Object in IQueryable LINQ in the DB side?

Comment: Sergey, it wasn't my idea to use JSON in the DB. But now I need to work with it. Maybe, it's not a good to deserialize it locally, because I will get problems with performance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no native support for JSON data in SQL server: [feature request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/673824/add-native-support-for-json-to-sql-server-a-la-xml-as-in-for-json-or-from-openjson)

Also you cannot deserialize string on database side. You need to get string from database, then deserialize it locally.

I would suggest you to create three columns FirstName, LastName and Position instead of storing serialized data. Or if you want data to be flexible think about using appropriate database (e.g. [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/))

Worth reading: [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/). As Phil says, parsing JSON is something inappropriate in SQL. But you can use his SQL function to convert your JSON data into table format.

---

Side notes:

To get count of all schedules use `allDataCount = context.Schedules.Count()`. You don't need to include related entities into generated query if you just looking for count.

This line `filteredDatacount = schedules.Count()` executes one more query, which you don't need. Simply get count after you got all filtered entities:

```
var filteredSchedules = schedules.ToList();
filteredDatacount = filteredSchedules.Count;
return filteredSchedules;
```

Comment: Is it good way to get Count (if I have large Data ~100 000 000) not on the DB side?

Comment: @Alexander if you have 100 000 000 entities, then `ToList()` is not best idea. I have doubts you need all these entities on client. After you call `ToList()` query is executed, new list created, and each row from query result is mapped on in-memory entity. So `filteredSchedules.Count` will cost nothing. It will just return length of in-memory list.